# Why my react app giving me 404 Error after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs

I founded a answer in stack overflow and i got this

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

this fixes my React App issue

But this giving me CORS error Why this is happening here

This is my server.js file

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");

const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorMiddleWare");

const { protect } = require("./middleware/authMiddleWare");

const adminRoute = require("./routes/adminRoute");

const adminControllerRoute = require("./routes/admincontrollerRoute");

const publicRoute = require("./routes/publicRoute");

const paymentRoute = require("./routes/paymentRoute");

const con = require("./config/db");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5050;

const app = express();

// MiddleWares

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/Uploads", express.static("Uploads"));

app.use("/Volunteers", express.static("Volunteers"));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cors());

// Admin Routes
app.use("/api/admin", adminRoute);

app.use("/admin/adminControllerRoute", protect, adminControllerRoute);

// Public Routes
app.use("/api/public", publicRoute);
app.use("/api/payment", paymentRoute);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World! Home Page.....");
});

// Error Middleware
app.use(errorHandler);

//connected to db
con.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
    });
  }
});
```

I am using axios to fetch data

```
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_BASE_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt,
  },
});

const getAllTestimonial = async () => {
  const response = await api.get("/api/public/getAllTestimonials");
  return response.data;
};
```

It is working fine  when I was not changing any thing in my .htacess file
Help me to solve the problem i am struggling to solve this

Comment: Did you try moving cors above the rest of the declarations? Your post title and the problem you're having are different things

Comment: Usually refresh 404 error  is a problem in htacces

Comment: This problem is occurred from htacces file When i remove this code <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>   from htacces my app is feching data but afer refreshin it is giving me 404 err  if i keft if it gives me cors error

Comment: Phix- Yes but nothing happen

Comment: I fund the solution Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
RewriteOptions inherit
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html   I replaced my .htaccess file with this lines of code and my website works properly